# Windows batch script: how to extract only th filename from a ftype command output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a windows batch file to save the current Python launcher command in use on the system.

this is what I come out with so far:

```
@echo off
ftype Python.file > tmpfile
set /p var= < tmpfile
...
```

say the output of `ftype` (and thus the content of var), is

```
Python.file="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L %*
```

how do I extract just "py" or "py.exe" from that string?

Comment: I will strongly suggest that you read [PEP 397 -- Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397), which may suggest your approach is not best advised.

Comment: @compo: My problem is that the machines where the python app will be installed have a huge number of costrains (security reasons), different setups depending on what department the employee belongs to, etc. etc.: in short it's a mess. The main.py of the app needs arguments to run which in turn will be provided by another batch file (users will be 85% illitterate when it comes to command line and the likes). and in that batch file I need to insert at installation time the name of the python launcher. or at least this is the best soultion I could come up with.

Comment: Your problem is that you clearly didn't read the content I linked which early on explains that a number of heuristics are used to locate the Python executable because file associations which use a' last installed Python version wins' strategy is not ideal.

Comment: I might not have made myself clear enough: some of the machine won't even have python installed, and the batch file will have to report it back. some will lack dependencies needed for the script to run, so they need to be installed via `python - m pip install whateverneeded`, finally the batch will generate a second batch (a launcher) which can be modved around (copied) and will take care of pointing to the script and its own libraries. corporate IT security policies (not me) force us devs to somersault. and often we don't come up with the smartest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (
   'ftype Python.file'
) do (
    for /f %%# in ("%%~b") do set "python=%%~nx#"
)
echo %python%
```

More about [for command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not that trivial, because the (executable) file name path does not always have to be quoted, even when containing spaces. If it is quoted, try:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol==" %%I in ('ftype Python.File') do (
    for %%K in (%%J) do (
        set "FileName=%%~nxK"
        goto :CONT
    )
)
:CONT
set "FileName"
```